# What does this name "X Perry Ment" mean?

Tags: phrases, slang, phrase-meaning

0

I read this sentence in a book named *Eyewitness testimony*：

*It gradually becomes evident that the article is satirical when the reader learns that the trial took place on April Fool’s Day, that the suit had been entered in the Supreme Court of Wundt County (Wilhelm Wundt is widely acknowledged as the father of experimental psychology) and that a Mr. X Perry Ment assisted with the defense.*

I'm really confused with the name *Mr. X Perry Ment* , although I can figure out it must be something satirical, but I still don't understand.

Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**X Perry Ment** is a play on the word [**experiment**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/experiment?locale=en).

Comment: OH, I finally get it, thank you.

Comment: Of a suitable standard on a site devoted to linguists? Doesn't 'answering' license further similar questions?